# Nginx Reverse Proxy Appending upstream port to my brower url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, httpserver

I have the following nginx configuration

```
upstream backend {
        server 172.22.3.5:8090;
    }

server {
       listen      443 default ssl;
       server_name example.io;
       
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.rsa;

       location /foo/ {
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_pass https://backend;
       }

 }
```

The challenge I am facing is that when I try to access **https://example.io/foo/hello** the browser changes my URL to **https://example.io:8090/foo/hello** and gives an error connection refused because there is no service running on the nginx server on port 8090.

Comment: This isn't coming from Nginx. This is coming from your application running at `172.22.3.5:8090`.

Comment: I do not understand if it is coming from the upstream service how come the url contains the server name of the nginx server with just the port appended.

Comment: You have passed the server name to your application in the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` statement. There is nothing in your Nginx configuration that would cause it to append the upstream port.